# How to install Netplan

Tags: netplan

On Ubuntu for rasberry-pi, I installed network-manager and netplan, started both services, but cannot find the usual /etc/netplan directory. What is missing?

Comment: If you perform a `ls -la /etc` and a `sudo ls /etc/` do you see it? What about `sudo ls -la /etc | grep netplan`?

Comment: Why did you need to "install" netplan at all?  The `netplan.io` package is installed by default in all Ubuntu images since Ubuntu 18.04, and the `/etc/netplan` directory is shipped as part of the `netplan.io` package.  So the question is, what did you do /before/ this that led you to need to install netplan?